Выражение "деньги зло"
В предложении
"Однако если вы будете цепляться за негативные установки и ложные стереотипы, связанные с деньгами, думать о том, что деньги зло, что они порождают трагедии"
необходимо ли тире между словами "деньги" и "зло"?
В книге нет, а ощущение есть, что надо...

Предложение выглядит незаконченным. Приведена только придаточная часть с союзом ЕСЛИ,

Правильно:
Однако если вы будете цепляться за негативные установки и ложные стереотипы, связанные с деньгами, думать о том, что деньги злО, // что они порождают трагЕдии...
Пояснение

Вот название статьи: ДЕньги — злО. Что стоит за этой фразой на самом деле.  Или вот:  ДЕньги – зло, энергия или срЕдство?!

Постановка тире в простом предложении не вызывает сомнения. На подлежащее падает ударение, пауза обозначена тире. В этом случае два ударения: на подлежащем и на сказуемом.

Если простое предложения входит в состав сложной конструкции, то расстановка ударений меняется, и тогда подлежащее деньги находится в безударной позиции, а ударение падает на сказуемое зло.

Но разве можно решать задачи по ударениям, с помощью интонационного анализа?! Из дискуссии на форуме:
 Да уж, ударения важнее, чем грамматика и смысл.  
 Действуйте по правилам Розенталя, а не по ударениям! Или 
 пойдите в РАН, чтобы они реформировали правила. Пусть 
 напишут, что надо писать по ударениям.


Удивительно, но в ПАС указано такое решение)


ПАС. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым
 § 10. Между подлежащим и именным сказуемым на месте 
 отсутствующей связки ставится тире, если подлежащее и 
 сказуемое выражены существительными в форме именительного 
 падежа:  Пушкинский край — край камней (Гейч.); Портрет 
 этот — единственное живописное изображение дочери Анны 
 Петровны Керн (Гейч.); 

 Примечание. Тире может не ставиться, если в письменной речи 
 отражено произношение с ЛОГИЧЕСКИМ УДАРЕНИЕМ  на сказуемом: 
 МОЯ СЕСТРА УЧИТЕЛЬНИЦА(ср.: Моя сестра — учительница — 
 ударение и на слове сестра, и на слове учительница).


Когда иностранцы изучают русский язык, даже при хорошем уровне знания, они спотыкаются о русское интонирование и ударные выделения тех или иных слов, так как в их родном языке интонирование может отличаться от русского. Но если им объяснить глубинную лингвистическую суть высказывания- тогда многое становится ясным и объясняет многие правила русского языка, вернее, выявляет суть правил, которые в русских школах предлагают просто запомнить. Например, во фразе  "Деньги- зло" не надо запоминать ( не всегда осознавая), где есть ударное выделение, а где- нет, чтобы решить поставить тире. Легче объяснить (в том числе и российскм школьникам), что когда предложение является по сути ОТОЖДЕСТВЛЕНИЕМ, то тире ставиться. А в предложении "Моя сестра учительница" тире можно не писать, потому что в этом предложении нет отождествления, а есть РАССШИРЕНИЕ информации о сестре. Кроме того, можно сказать " моя сестра работает учительницей", но нельзя сказать, что "Деньги работают злом". В предложении с сестрой речь идёт об объективном информировании, а  в предложении с деньгами- имеет место субъективное отождествление.

Понимать до конца все нюансы не обязательно, потому что у разных людей они могут быть пластичны как плазма. Важно дать человеку хотя бы минимум опор на ориентацию в своих собственных интенциях в момент построения речи.

Уважаемая Sharon, благодарю Вас за ваш ответ. Я не настаиваю на том, чтобы мой ответ был принят Вами. Я языковед и лингвист по образованию и 35 лет преподавала сначала русский как родной, а потом русский как иностранный. Именно благодаря таким моим объяснением иностранцы начинают понимать логику построения звучащей речи. К моим размышлениям можно прислушаться, но не обязательно возводить их в абсолют. Если мой ответ вам лично не нравится, это вовсе не означает, что он не имеет право быть признанным ответом. Прислушиваться к таким размышлениям тоже надо уметь. Бесконечные рассуждения на тему, ч
